# Calculate sum of norms using this method.

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have a metric space $(\mathbb{R}^2,d)$ where $d$ is the $2$-dimensional euclidean distance and we need to find the sum of the distances between the origin $(0,0)$ and all points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (yes, the result is infinite).

The distance from the origin to $x=(x_1,x_2)$ is just the norm of $x$.

One method is to directly sum all the norms using

$$\sum_{x\in\mathbb{R}^2}||x||_2=\sum_{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2}\sqrt{{x_1}^2+{x_2}^2}$$

And the other one, the one I'm having trouble with, is based on this equation:

$$dz^2=d{x_1}^2+d{x_2}^2$$

The problem is I don't know where to put the integral in order to sum them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just

$$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \|(x,y)\|_2 \,dxdy = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \,dxdy$$

Now introduce polar coordinates $x = r\cos\phi$, $y = r\sin\phi$. The Jacobian of the transformation is $r$.

$$= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \sqrt{r^2} r\,drd\phi = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty r^2\,drd\phi = +\infty$$

The expression $$\sum_{x\in\mathbb{R}^2} \|x\|_2$$

is not even defined without introducing the concept of summability on directed sets via the convergence of nets.